# SwiftUI Sticky/Pinned Bottom Sheet View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, bottom-sheet

I'm working on implementing a very simple bottom sheet in SwiftUI, but I am hitting an issue where I can't figure out how to get the bottom of the sheet to "stick" or "pin" to the bottom of the screen/view.

Here is the code I'm using for the bottom sheet

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BottomSheetView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool

    @ViewBuilder let content: Content

    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                ChildSizeReader(size: $contentSize) {
                    content
                }
            }
            .frame(
                width: geometry.size.width,
                height: contentSize.height,
                alignment: .top
            )
            .clipShape(
                Path(
                    UIBezierPath(
                        roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: geometry.size.width, height: contentSize.height),
                        byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
                        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 16.0, height: 16.0)
                    )
                    .cgPath
                )
            )
            .frame(
                height: geometry.size.height,
                alignment: .bottom
            )
            .offset(y: isOpen ? 0.0 : contentSize.height)
            .animation(
                .spring()
                    .speed(1.25)
            )
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}

struct BottomSheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BottomSheetView(isOpen: .constant(true)) {
            Text("Bottom Sheet")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 200.0)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.Primary.primaryRed)
                )
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an image of the resulting view

[image: bottom_sheet_screenshot]

The view as it sits statically is fine, but when the animation happens to open the bottom sheet, it bounces up and you can see below the view for a brief second. I imagine this will also become more apparent when I add a drag gesture to allow the user to interact with the bottom sheet (It's controlled by a button at the moment).

I'm looking for almost a stretchy view where when it is expanded open, at its max content height, the view can bounce up, and the bottom will stick to the bottom of the screen. Is this possible, and if so, how can I go about getting it to do that?

Comment: What is `ChildSizeReader`?

Comment: You looking for something like this? https://www.tiktok.com/@swiftpunkenterprise/video/7025809557188381957?sender_device=pc&sender_web_id=7027597624396776966&is_from_webapp=v1&is_copy_url=0

Comment: @aheze, `ChildSizeReader` is a View that binds the size of its child to a CGSize so you can use a child's size outside of its direct view hierarchy. I'm not sure who the original author is, but if you do a search for it, you should find some posts about it.

@swiftPunk, yes, that's basically what I'm looking for.

Comment: @RPK: You are over complicating your view with path if your goal is something like in my TikTok video.

Comment: @swiftPunk The path is to round only the top corners. As far as I'm aware, that's the only way to selectively round corners in SwiftUI. Are you just extending your view below the bottom of the screen and not allowing it to open far enough to see the bottom?

Comment: That can be also a way, or offset another way, the end result is important, the way should be easy and less CPU.